# Send files via XMLHttpRequest on another Server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

i like try to send a POST form with attached files via javascript XMLHttpRequest.

Here is my Code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('start_file_upload_button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function()
        {
        document.getElementById("file_upload_button_button").style.display = "none";
        var mfs         = document.getElementsByName('MAX_FILE_SIZE')[0].value,
            to_up_files = document.getElementById('to_upload_files_field'),
            status      = document.getElementById('file_upload_status_text'),
            errorlog    = document.getElementById('file_upload_error_log'),
            progress    = document.getElementById('file_upload_progress_bar');
        for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('to_upload_files_field').files.length; ++i) {
            document.getElementById('remove_link_' + i).style.display = "none"; }
        for(var i = 0; i < <?php echo $__CONFIG['UPLOAD']['MAX_FILE_AT_ONCE']; ?>; ++i)
            {
            if(typeof(document.getElementById('to_upload_files_field').files[i]) == "undefined") break;
            var upload   = document.getElementById('to_upload_files_field').files[i],
                filename = upload.name,
                filesize = upload.size,
                mfs      = mfs; alert(filename);
            if(filesize > <?php echo $USER_DATA['UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE']; ?>)
                {
                var errorelem  = document.createElement('span');
                var errorbreak = document.createElement('br');
                errorelem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Die Datei "' + filename + '" ist zu Groß'));
                errorelem.appendChild(errorbreak);
                errorlog.appendChild(errorelem);
                break;
                }
            if(<?php echo $USER_DATA['SPACE_MAX']; ?> < (filesize + <?php echo $USER_DATA['SPACE_USED']; ?>))
                {
                var errorelem  = document.createElement('span');
                var errorbreak = document.createElement('br');
                errorelem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Die Datei "' + filename + '" past nicht mehr auf die Platte'));
                errorelem.appendChild(errorbreak);
                errorlog.appendChild(errorelem);
                break;
                }
            if(filesize > (<?php echo $USER_DATA['TRAFFIC_PER_DAY'] - $USER_DATA['TRAFFIC_USED']; ?>) && (<?php echo $USER_DATA['TRAFFIC_PER_DAY'] - $USER_DATA['TRAFFIC_USED']; ?>) != 0)
                { // SPERRE EINBAUEN DAS ES NUR GEPRÜFT WIRD WENN DIE TRAFFIC ÜBERWACHUNG AKTIVIERT IST
                var errorelem  = document.createElement('span');
                var errorbreak = document.createElement('br');
                errorelem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Die Datei "' + filename + '" braucht mehr traffic als du hast'));
                errorelem.appendChild(errorbreak);
                errorlog.appendChild(errorelem);
                break;
                }
            status.innerHTML = "Lade " + filename + " hoch...";
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('POST', 'http://www.domain.tld/user/upload/', true);
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
            request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt)
                {
                var uploaded = Number((100 / evt.total) * evt.loaded).toFixed(2);
                progress.innerHTML = "Upload zu " + uploaded + "% fertig";
                if(uploaded = 100.00)
                    {
                    progress.innerHTML = "Datei wird verarbeitet... Bitte warten...";
                    }
                }, false);
            request.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
                alert("lol2"); }, false);
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('upload_key', '<?php echo $upload_key; ?>');
            data.append('MAX_FILE_SIZE', mfs);
            data.append('file', upload);
            request.send(data);
            request.onload = function()
                {
                if(this.status == 200)
                    {
                    alert("lol");
                    }
                else
                    {
                    alert("Some Upload Error");
                    }
                };
            }
        }, false);
    }, false);
```

The Script works great and without problems when i'll send it to "http://www.domain.tld/user/upload/"
but i like to send it to "http://sub.somain.com/store/" and this is not working, why?

Console log by send to "www.domain.tld":

> [12:21:51.085] POST `http://www.domain.tld/user/upload/` [HTTP/1.1 200
>   OK 5ms]

Console log by send to "sub.domain.tld":

> [12:21:17.786] OPTIONS `http://sub.domain.tld/store/` [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]

The servers run the same script, what can i do?

Comment: This is security restriction I guess. So it will be impossible.

Comment: a CORS issue i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript will not allow you to make requests between domains, howewer, this behavior can be changed if the server sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the name of whitelisted domain.

### CORS

As I've said, you can yse special response header to allow cross-domain request. This method is called **CORS** - *Cross Origin resource sharing*.
It is used like that:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.domain.tld");
```

Unfortunatelly, this was only recently introduced and has poor browser support.

#### [CORS Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors)

### JSONP

Another method to fire cross domain request is JSONP. This can only be applyed to GET requests. Because you are sending POST, I will not introduce this further.

### Iframe

You may have forgotten about possibility of using an Iframe. Of course, in that case you will not get any return values and it will be impossible to monitor upload process. But you can still inform user about sucess if you fire `alert()` function in the iframe. Also, you can reload page from the iframe:

```
window.top.location = "domain.com/script.php?upload=sucessfull";
```

Comment: Change in an iframe is a good idea, but how do I make it that the upload progress will still be displayed

Comment: That is the problem I've stated - you will not. It is not possible yet. Your only chance is to go for Flash or Java uploader and change your whole application. Why don't you move the upload HTML page on the another domain?

Comment: I'm not sure if the comment above is ironical or not, but anyway - why not to put the upload for whole, even with javascript, on the remote domain and show it in the iframe on `www.domain.com`. This is the very last solution I can figure out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking the "same origin policy". You can return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, which will tell the browser to allow the request, however [browser support isn't 100%](http://enable-cors.org/client.html). Take a look at [the documentation for your web server or programming language](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

If you need 100% browser support then you might be better off uploading into /tmp on the parent domain, and then firing off a cURL request to the sub-domain.

Comment: exactly what I wanted to avoid

Comment: The cURL method isn't desirable, I'll admit that.